# Sarrus determinant rule: references, extensions

Tags: linear-algebra, determinants, permutations, symmetric-groups

SEEKING REFERENCES FOR SARRUS' RULE AND EXTENSIONS

An undergraduate came to me with an identity for 4x4 determinants that is actually correct:

$\det(A)=h(A)+h(RA)+h(R^{2}A)$

where R cyclically permutes the last three rows of the matrix A. I wont define h here but,  except for the signs of the terms, it is the usual incorrect extension of Sarrus Rule that is familiar to anyone who has has taught linear algebra (His identity  is not the Laplace expansion, as it has three 4x4 matrices, rather than four 3x3 matrices. )

Is something like this known? Mathscinet lists a paper Monaco and Monaco that might be relevant, but my library couldnt  get it. I haven't even found the original reference for Sarrus' rule itself.

Eric Schmutz

Comment: So the trick is that every permutation $\pi\in S_4$ can be uniquely written as $\sigma\xi$, where $\sigma\in Z_3$ (here, $Z_3$ is seen as a subgroup of $S_4$ acting on the four-element set by cyclically permuting its last three elements) and $\xi\in D_4$ (where $D_4$ is the dihedral group generated by the shift $\left(x\mapsto x+1\mod 4\right)$ and the reflection $\left(x\mapsto -x\mod 4\right)$). The $\xi$ corresponds to the application of the Sarrus rule, and the $\sigma$ corresponds to $1$, $R$ rsp. $R^2$. If I find some generalization of this, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: I should have denoted $Z_3$ by $C_3$; it's the cyclic group on $3$ elements. Note that $D_4$ is the dihedral group with $8$ (not $4$) elements; I know that there are some conflicting notations here.

Comment: What's $h$? And "Sarrus' Rule"?

Comment: There is an amazing book on determinants and their history by Thomas Muir. That's the first place I'd look.

Comment: And if it's not in Muir, try Dodgson, An Elementary Treatise On Determinants. Dodgson, of course, is better known as Lewis Carroll. 

Comment: Muir is indeed amazing, but I wouldn't call it an easy reading. It seems to me that British mathematicians used to work with incredibly bulky and obfuscated notation until the middle of the 20th Century, and Muir could be the best example of this. When have you last seen the word "evanescence" in the meaning of "being equal to zero"? In Muir's book, you will read this more than once. And not only doesn't he distinguish between a matrix and its determinant (denoting both as "determinant"), he actually seems proud of it (as seen from his comments on some papers which do use the word "matrix").

Comment: Here is a sample: "The Law of Extensible Minors is : If any identical relation be established between a number of the minors of a determinant or between the determinant itself and a number of its minors, the determinants being denoted by means of their principal diagonals, then a new theorem is always obtainable by merely choosing a line of new letters with new suffixes and annexing it to the end of the diagonal of every determinant, including those of order 0, occurring in the identity." Well, this belongs to the half of the results that I actually understood.

Comment: Muir got his book published in 1905. Notation, language, usage and what not has changed immensely since then in the mathematical science! Your complaints are in the same spirit of those I heard from a student some time ago who very seriously complained that Gauss wrote in latin...

Comment: My quotes are actually from 1923 (the fourth volume of Muir). And I must say I have seen better notations in literature from that time. van der Waerden's Modern Algebra is just 7 years younger!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found references to  the Sarrus determinant rule and to an extension of it. In The Quarterly journal of pure and applied mathematics, Volume 38 which is available on Google books in the article "A fourth list of writings on determinants". On page 239 There is a reference to what I believe is Sarrus original result. Then on page 350 there is a reference to an extension of Sarrus' original result. I believe that part one of Muir's book on determinants and their history is available on Google books

Comment: What is the extension?  (I think you mean page 250.)

Answer (score 10):

The logic behind this does extend to general $n\times n$ determinants, though probably not as nicely as you wish. Note that I am taking the liberty to replace "last" by "first" in "where R cyclically permutes the last three rows of the matrix A". It doesn't matter, because Sarrus' rule is invariant under cyclic shift, and a simple cyclic shift turns the last three rows to the first three rows.

Consider the alternating group $A_{n-1}$ embedded into the symmetric group $S_n$: every element of $A_{n-1}$ is a permutation of the set $\left\lbrace 1,2,...,n-1\right\rbrace$, and thus can be seen as a permutation of the set $\left\lbrace 1,2,...,n\right\rbrace$ which leaves $n$ fixed.

Also consider the dihedral group $D_n$ defined as the subgroup of $S_n$ generated by the cyclic shift $\left(x\mapsto x+1\mod n\right)$ and the reflection $\left(x\mapsto n+1-x\right)$.

Then, every element $\pi\in S_n$ can be uniquely written as $\pi=\sigma\xi$ with $\sigma\in A_{n-1}$ and $\xi\in D_n$. In fact, $\xi$ is uniquely determined by the conditions $\left(\pi\xi^{-1}\right)\left(n\right)=n$ and $\mathrm{sign}\left(\pi\xi^{-1}\right)=1$, and then $\sigma$ results.

Now, write the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix in the form $\sum_{\pi\in S_n}\mathrm{sign}\pi\cdot\prod ...=\sum_{\sigma\in A_{n-1}}\sum_{\xi\in D_n}\mathrm{sign}\xi\cdot\prod ...$. Each inner sum $\sum_{\xi\in D_n}\mathrm{sign}\xi\cdot\prod ...$ is the naive "Sarrus determinant" of some permutation of the matrix; which permutation it actually is is decided by the $\sigma$.

For $n=3$, we have $A_{n-1}=A_2=1$, so the outer sum $\sum_{\sigma\in A_{n-1}}$ has only one term, and the "Sarrus determinant" is the real determinant.

For $n=4$, we have $A_{n-1}=A_3=C_3$ (the cyclic group with $3$ elements), so the outer sum $\sum_{\sigma\in A_{n-1}}$ has three terms, and it follows that the determinant of a $4\times 4$ matrix can be written as a sum of three "Sarrus determinants". A closer look at the sum shows which ones.

Answer (score 2):

I've posted a diagram version of 4x4 Sarrus here: http://www.theoremoftheday.org/GeometryAndTrigonometry/Sarrus/Sarrus4x4.pdf

Comment: Seems confusing! See this one https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijem/2016/9382739/